# Fortiy Scan label window open as XSS. How to write it to avoid XSS in scan

Tags: javascript, xss, fortify

I have inherited an old classic ASP program. In it the coder used the below code to open windows. I have to scan the program with a Fortify scan to try and eliminate the problems. The scan labels everyone of these as Cross site scripting.  I added the Server.URLEncode to try and get the scan to not recognize them as XSS problems, didn't work. All of the pages the code open are in the website none go outside for external pages.  Can someone help me with the code that will keep the scan from marking these as XSS.  Thanks for the help.

```
<script>
  function CloseRejectWindow() {
  window.opener.parent.parent.location = "107_ETAR_frames.asp?status_id= <%=Server.URLEncode(status_id)%>"
window.close()
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is not the url part. the problem is here "window.opener.parent.parent" this will be treated as a security violation.I don't have any idea on fortify scan. If that line is absolutely required, the only pointer i can give is, see if you can configure fortify scan to add this as an exception

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of any other way to write the code that will still open the window.